# Best practice to implement disable resource in REST

Tags: rest

I would like to know if there is any best practice available to implement a "disable action" using REST. The disable would mean that data in all the fields is purged but the resource exists itself.

Example:

If the representation of a resource in JSON is

```
{"id":"1", "data":["a", "b", "c"]}
```

then after "disable" the representation of the resource in JSON becomes

```
{"id":"1", "data":[]}
```

I am thinking of adding a disable field to the resource like,

```
{"id":"1", "data":["a", "b", "c"], "disable":false}
```

and then doing a partial update (PATCH) to set "disable" to true. Now comes the catch, I want to automatically remove the data when the "disable" is set to true, however, I do not know if this is a good approach. I would like your input and any possible alternatives that you think are better.

The request could look something like (other ideas are welcome)

PATCH /resources/1?disable=true

now if we GET the resource /resources/1, we should GET

```
{"id":"1", "data":[], "disable":true}
```

Do you guys think it is a good approach or I need to do it some other way. The key issue is to figure out a good/standard way to update other fields of the resource when one field is updated.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there isn't a best practice.  However, after building a few RESTful API's I have an opinion.

Here are a few thoughts to consider:

If you are going to persist the disable attribute then putting it in the JSON is probably appropriate because it becomes part of the resource.  In other words, does disable have long term meaning to this resource such that a consumer of the API would perhaps display this value in a meaningful way to some user.

However, if you aren't going to persist the disable attribute and merely change how the data is returned based on disable, then I would do something like this:  http:///myresource?disable=true.  I prefer this because disable wouldn't be an attribute of the resource rather a function of the api which changes its representation.

From my perspective the representation of the data should be separate from the resource itself.  Perhaps a way to think of this is am I returning JSON or XML.  Am I returning JSON disabled or JSON enabled.

I'm not certain a right answer exists here, but I hope that helps.